# Lock Screen notifications flutter

Tags: notifications, flutter

How would you implement notifications in flutter both in the navigation drawer and the lock screen notifications?

I don't seem to get a way to do that

Comment: Tell us what you got so far. which technology are you using for the notifications?

Comment: @boformer firebase

Comment: You have to provide more information. What kind of behaviour do you want for the sidebar? A list that is exactly synchronized with the system notifications? Or just a (live) list of all notifications in chronological order? Dismissible or not? What kind of system are you using to send the notifications? Do you have a full backend server with a database? Do you require an app that works on iOS and Android? Is the app bound to a single device, or is it possible that a user uses the same account on multiple devices (so notifications must be synchronized)? Please add this info to your question.

Comment: @boformer That comment has helped me a lot. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: @HardRock did you solve it? if so, can you please provide the solution?

Comment: @HardRock Did you find solution?